# I can't jump from main page to another activity at my project

Tags: android, android-activity

I need help with my first project, which I'm building now.

My project contains three activities:

- the First is the main one which has two Buttons (1st is called Annonce and the  Other is called Index).
- the second activity is called Annonce as the same with the buttons mentioned above.
- the third activity is named Index as the same also mentioned above.

I want...
When I click on the Annonce Button from the main activity, Android takes me to the second activity, and the same thing with the other button (Index) and of course I can return back to the main activity.

My main.Java file is:

```
    @Override 
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
        setContentView(R.layout.main); 

        annonce = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Annonce); 
        index = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Index);

        annonce.setOnClickListener(this);
        index.setOnClickListener(this);
    } 

    public void onClick(View src) {
      Intent annonce = new Intent(this, Annonce.class);
      startActivity(annonce);
      Intent index = new Intent(this, Index.class);
      startActivity(index);
      finish();
    } 
}
```

Comment: call only one intent You are use two

Answer (score 1):

What do you do? You are trying in one press button jump to 2 pages. You should to remove one Intent and your 2nd mistake, you are trying to jump onto bottons - its funny =)

Answer (score 0):

you are close, but there might be a problem with the `onClick` code.

Try this instead of what you have:

```
public void onClick(View src) {
  if (src == annonce){
      Intent annonce = new Intent(this, Annonce.class);
      startActivity(annonce);
  }else if (src == index){
      Intent index = new Intent(this, Index.class);
      startActivity(index);
  }
}
```

Two changes:  IF/Else statement to determine which view was pushed (you were trying to start both activitie, but you only want to start one depending on which button).  Also, don't call finish() here.  You don't need it here, and that line will kill your application!

Also, in the future, post some more information about what is happening! I am assuming the App closes when you press any button (because of that call to finish()) but next time tell us!

Comment: dear edthethird! thanks for your replay and I done what you wrote here but unfortunently my application stopped can you please help me more. good luck

Comment: we are going to need more information.  When it it stops, is there is a stacktrace?

Comment: Dear edthethird. Thx again, this what come upp on the consol (ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.ukadhmarket.wadood/.UkadhMarket }) and then it says it stopped without giving any trace. if U send me your email I can send U the hole project, maybe U can fix out my problem, my email is wadood56@hotmail.com.

Answer (score 0):

you incorrect create `OnClickListener`

write this code:

```
OnClickListener annonceBtnClick= new OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
         // TODO Auto-generated method stub
          Intent annonce = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Annonce.class);
          startActivity(annonce);
       }
     };
```

Do same with Index button

Comment: Thank Budgie for your fast replay ... I did what you recomanded for the two buttons but.... It gives me an error on the second startactivity as here(The method startActivity(Intent) in the type Activity is not applicable for the arguments (Button)) agian thanks a lot and I´d be very greatfull if you can send me the full code.

Comment: oh. of course, rename your Intents. they named likewise your buttons.

Comment: `annonce.setOnClickListener(annonceBtnClick); index.setOnClickListener(indexBtnClick)``Intent intent1 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Annonce.class);startActivity(intent1);` create indexBtnClick yet

Comment: dear budgie, thx agian, but realy I´m lost now. Can U pl. write the hole code one time more, for both bottons (annonce and inde).

Answer (score 0):

A few things:

- You're finishing your main activity before you're even giving your new activities a chance to appear. You don't need to call `finish()` unless you actually want to quit an activity.
- You're trying to start two activities at the same time.

When you want to set click handlers, you need to ensure that the view that's being clicked is the one you open activity for.

That means

```
public void onClick (View src) {
    switch (src.getId()) {
    case R.id.annonce_button:
        startActivity(new Intent("com.myPackage.myActivity");
        break;
    case R.id.index_button:
        startActivity(new Intent("com.myPackage.myIndexActivity");
        break;
    }
}
```

you have one case for every ID that you hit, ensuring that you're only starting the activity for the proper button click.

Of course the above code assumes that you have set IDs on your buttons. That way those IDs match up with R.id.XXXXXXX and you can use them for quick checks.

Comment: dear jlindenbaum. sorry but your code did not work with me, I do not know why, but the application stopped at working. I´d be very greatfull if you´d help me more. thanks a lot.

Comment: "Did not work" is a pretty vague phrase. What didn't work? Did you modify it to meet your needs?

Comment: I can send you the whole project, if you´d send me ur mail, maybe U can fix it to me. my mail:wadood56@hotmail.com. sorry to bother you.

Comment: Edit your post with your modified code since you've started implementing the changes suggested here.

Answer (score 0):

I would update the main.xml file and add these lines to the buttons:

```
android:clickable="true"
android:onClick="annonce_button_handler"
```

and

```
android:clickable="true"
android:onClick="index_button_handler"
```

Then I would create those methods in my main Activity, like this:

```
public void annonce_button_handler(){
    Intent annonce = new Intent(this, Annonce.class);
    startActivity(annonce);
}

public void index_button_handler(){
    Intent index = new Intent(this, Index.class);
    startActivity(index);
}
```

That will allow you to have an activity that does NOT implement the onClickListener, and still allow you to implement multiple clickable things in your code. BTW, that should work for almost any element you put in your .xml file.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

May be its too late.. but still wanted to add

dont forget to add both of your Activity in Manifest

Answer (score 0):

I hope you created your Activities and have Registered with manifest file.

now :-

```
    @Override 
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
            setContentView(R.layout.main); 

            annonce = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Annonce); 
            index = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Index);

            annonce.setOnClickListener(this);
            index.setOnClickListener(this);
        } 

        public void onClick(View src)
          {

              if(src == annonce )
              {
                    //start activity here
                   Intent intent1 = new Intent(this,activityToSwitch);
                   startactivity(intent1);
              }
                if(src == index)
              {
                    //start activity here
                   Intent intent2 = new Intent(this,activityToSwitch);
                   startactivity(intent2);
              }

         }
```